# Does Ruby allow to return a slice of an array?

Tags: ruby

Perl allows you to use the '..' operator to return a slice from an array.  So if I wanted cells 4 through 8 from an array, I could this:

```
sample_array[4..8]
```

And if I assigned that to a new array, it would only have those 5 cells.  Is there an operator like this for Ruby?

Thanks.

Comment: It can also be done as `sample_array[4,8]`, which is actually faster.

Comment: @Jesse sample_array[4,8] is different from sample_array[4..8]. The first one starts at index 4 and grabs the next 8 indexes. The second one gets items at index 4 through 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question.  The Array#[] method can take a range, and return slices of that array.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have answered your own question, but fwiw, here is the [Array#[] documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002160) which shows some more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, wouldn't trying it yourself be faster than asking?

Yes, there's such operator. Working exactly like you described.